# How change the dropdown according to the previous dropdown data changed in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have 5 dropdown candidatename,vendor name , client name, jobtitle respectively. i want if the candidate name is changing with the candidate name all othere columns should change accordingly.
Note: all the dropdowns are directly taken from database columns.

here i am calling all the columns in aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control select2" 
    data-placeholder="Choose Consultant..." TabIndex="-1" 
    aria-hidden="true" ID="dd_consultantName" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="candidatename" 
    DataValueField="candidatename" 
    OnTextChanged="dd_consultantName_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem class="text-muted">
        --Choose Candidate Name--        
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectiontest %>" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [candidatename] FROM [tb_test] WHERE ([mail] = @mail )">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="mail" Name="mail" SessionField="mail" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and here i am getting all the candidate name like the same i am calling all the fileds like vendor name client name etc.in this i have used ontextchange event and it is refreshing the page and but throughing the error is like "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: vendorname".

and here is my code behind i am sharing:

```
public void getcandidatename()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_testing", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "selectcandidatename");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", Session["mail"]);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candidatename", dd_consultantName.SelectedItem.Text);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dd_vendorname.SelectedItem.Text = dr["vendorname"].ToString();
            dd_clientname.SelectedItem.Text = dr["clientname"].ToString();
            dd_companyname.SelectedItem.Text = dr["companyname"].ToString();
            dd_jobtitle.SelectedItem.Text = dr["jobtitle"].ToString();
        }
    }
    dr.Close(); con.Close();
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
}
```

here i should get the data with respective candidatename, but the problem is i could not get the data please help me.
i want it in asp.net c# if any one can help i will be thankfull to him/her
thank you

and please ignore my english it is bad.

and here is the query from my database
select candidatename from tb_testcandidates where mail=@mail and candidate is not null

Comment: The exception you say comes up right when the "while" loop starts? Post the complete exception message because it appears that the sp_testing procedure is not returning anything. How are you loading the other dropdown lists?

Comment: hello julian here i have edited mycode please review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand is that if you want to change one or more of a dropdownlist it can be done without C# code, simply using `SqlDataSource` and specifying the query or stored procedure together with the parameters and the association of the dropdownlist, I will mention an example with base to exercise your question:

**ASPX Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListConsultant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    CssClass="form-control select2" data-placeholder="Choose Consultant..." TabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="candidatename" DataValueField="candidate_id">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [candidate_id], [candidatename] FROM [tb_test] WHERE [mail] = @mail;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="mail" Name="mail" SessionField="mail" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListVendor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control select2" 
    aria-hidden="true" data-placeholder="Choose Consultant..." TabIndex="-1"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="vendorname" DataValueField="vendor_id">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="EXEC sp_testing @type, @mail, @candidatename;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListConsultantName" Name="candidatename" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="SelectedItem" />  
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="mail" Name="mail" SessionField="mail" />          
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="selectcandidatename" Name="type" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListClient" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control select2" 
    aria-hidden="true" data-placeholder="Choose Consultant..." TabIndex="-1"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="clientname" DataValueField="client_id">
</asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>"
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="EXEC sp_testing @type, @mail, @candidatename;"> // Other procedure? or include all columns in the same procedure
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListConsultantName" Name="candidatename" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="SelectedItem" />  
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="mail" Name="mail" SessionField="mail" />          
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="selectcandidatename" Name="type" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you can see, the `DropDownListVendor` and `DropDownListClient` elements use the same stored procedure to catch the information depending on what is selected in the `DropDownListConsultant` element, and use different columns from the query (instead of using a different stored procedure for DropdownList). This is what I see in your code example.

Let me know if it works, I hope I have helped you!

Comment: hello julian thank you for your reply, I have already tried this method but the problem is it is not taking the parameter as u have mentioned but thank you now I got the idea how to do. Thank You. adding a statement if anyone using this method you have to write different different method for each dropdown where u have to give the parameter as the id of before dropdown.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm glad my answer was helpful!